# How to build sets of entity records using Breeze and local storage

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I'm trying to create an off-line data collection app, using AngularJS.
I think, adding Breeze.js should help with saving and querying data to and from the browser local storage:
1) present the user with angular data entry form
2) when the "save" button is clicked - create a new Breeze entity and store it locally
3) the next time this form is used - create a second entity, and add/save it as a part of the same collection
 I was wandering if anyone have tried to do something similar and could give me some pointers of how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's viable and these links should help you to get started:

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/querying-locally

You also might want to check this Angular sample aswell:

http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-angular

One caveat you have to have in mind is that Breeze will need to load the model's metadata from somewhere. Typically you hit a Web API asynchronously and get the metadata from there. However, on your particular scenario you should give a look at trying to load your metadata from a script file. Here's an how-to and discussion about it:

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/load-metadata-script